# Get multiple substrings between " or '

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to get substrings when the substrings are either located between a ' (single quote) or " (double quote)

Example:

Input: The "quick" brown "fox" 'jumps' over the 'lazy dog'

Output: ['quick', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy dog']

I have tried doing this with a regex but fell flat.

```
const string = "The "quick" brown "fox" 'jumps' over the 'lazy dog'"     
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/;
console.log(strippedText.match(pattern));
```

But it only returns the first single quoted or double quotes word.

Comment: Use the global flag, `g`, after the last `/` in the pattern, and change the function from `match` to `matchAll`. So: `pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;`. This returns an array of arrays, so you'll need to do processing on that to get the normal array that you want.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thank you, I knew it was something simple I overlooked.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Please put this in an answer, and Ardz, please accept it. This will help other people find an answer.

Comment: @Tom Okay, I've posted an answer & shown the extra processing needed to fix the nested array and remove the extra quotes

Answer (score 1):

Use the global flag, `g`, after the last `/` in the pattern, and change the function from `match` to `matchAll`. So: `pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;`. This returns an array of arrays, so you'll need to do processing on that to get the normal array that you want.

```js
const string = `The "quick" brown "fox" 'jumps' over the 'lazy dog'`; // Uses backticks since we use " and '
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g; // Pattern has the global flag "g" at the end so it allows multiple matches
const matches = [...string.matchAll(pattern)] // Convert RegExpStringIterator into array with the spread operator "..."
  .map(([_, first, second]) => first ?? second); // Convert the array of arrays into something sensible.
console.log(matches);
```

Without mapping, matches would look like this:

```json
[
    [
        "\"quick\"",
        null,
        "quick"
    ],
    [
        "\"fox\"",
        null,
        "fox"
    ],
    [
        "'jumps'",
        "jumps",
        null
    ],
    [
        "'lazy dog'",
        "lazy dog",
        null
    ]
]
```

So with this line:

```js
.map(([_, first, second]) => first ?? second)
```

We destructure the inner array, discarding the 0th index (which is the whole match, including things inside a "do no match" group `(?:)`, so it includes the quotes at the beginning and end), and extracting the 1st and 2nd indices. The `first ?? second` means that if `first` is not `null` or `undefined`, it returns `first`, otherwise it returns `second`.